# Tension at the ends of an elastic rod being acted by external forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, elasticity

Consider an elastic rod (mass m, length l) being acted by external forces as shown[image]

What would be the tension at the end A and B(marked as green)? And why?

My teacher took the tensions at A to be F and at B to be 2F, but isn't the element at the end A accelerated in the forward direction so it should have tension more than F. Similarly, tension at B should be less than 2F ?

Comment: What affect do you acceleration has on tension? The tension is the cause of acceleration, not vice versa.

Comment: Also since the rod is elastic(rigid), all the particles on it will have same acceleration.

Comment: i agree, for the element at the end to accelerate, it must have some net forward force, so tension should be different than the forces applied

Comment: All the particles would have same acceleration in case of a rigid body, yes, that's what i am saying, particle at the end would have some acceleration

Comment: So what should the tensions be at the ends? Have you drawn some free body diagrams to figure it out? What have you tried?

Comment: @PinkAura The tension at end B is $2F$. What you're talking about is: If I take a teeny tiny element at end B of mass $dm$ and length $dx$ (like a slice from a loaf of bread), then the tension towards the right will be $2F-adm$, and towards the left it'll be$2F$.

Comment: @StutiGupta yes i am talking about this. I was not really sure if we can neglect that. I think i would need to delete this question, if that's the case

Comment: We are not neglecting anything here. What your teacher said was about the end point, not the small element. We generally don't discuss internal forces (like tension towards right at the element near B) because they don't add value or anything; we can analyse the whole body with external forces only. The teacher was speaking of the rigid body as a whole, and you're talking about an element of the body. Both approaches are correct, but should not be mixed up.

Comment: While analysing the whole rod, these internal forces add up and cancel out, and the force is only due to external forces; to see that, consider another element right next to the first then it's tension towards right will be $2F-adm$(Newton's third law) and similarly it'll have a tension $2F-2adm$ towards left, similarly all the way up to end A.

Comment: @Stuti Gupta nope, my teacher was actually finding the tension at a point in the rod using integration, he put the limit of left end as F

Comment: At the _point_ A, it'll be F. At the different ends of a little _element_, the tensions will be different (as explained in my previous comment).

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is correct. Because the rod has  non-zero mass, tension will vary along the rod from $F$ at end A to $2F$ at end B.

If we consider a small element of the rod with length $\delta x$ and mass $\delta m$ then the difference $\delta T$ between the tensions acting to the right and to the left on that element $\delta m$ must be sufficient to accelerate it with an acceleration of $\frac F m$ which is the acceleration of the whole rod. So

$\displaystyle \delta T = \frac F m \delta m$

If we assume that the rod has the same cross sectional area $A$ and the same density $\rho$ along its whole length then

$\delta m = \rho A \delta x
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \delta T = \frac F m \rho A \delta x$

But the whole mass of the rod $m$ is equal to $\rho A l$, so

$\displaystyle \delta T = \frac F l \delta x$

In the limit as $\delta T$ and $\delta x$ become small we have

$\displaystyle \frac {dT}{dx} = \frac F l$

and since $\frac F l$ is a constant, we can see that $T$ must vary linearly along the rod. We know that $T=F$ at end A and $T=2F$ at end B, so at a distance $x$ from end A we have

$\displaystyle T(x) = F + \frac F l x = F \left( \frac {l+x} l \right)$

Comment: Just a thought,- shouldn't we calculate integral of $\int_x^{x+k} \frac {F}{l} dl$ to get tension between $x$ and $x+k$ ? In this case answer would be $T(x,k) = F \ln \left(\frac {x+k}{x} \right)$, i.e., thus it's not linear for every practical purpose, because we can't poke physically at $x$ in rod, just at some $dx$ range ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas That's my fault for bad notation - I was using $\delta l$ for the length of a small element and using $l$ for the fixed length of the whole rod. I have edited my answer, replacing $\delta l$ with $\delta x$.

Comment: @gandalf61 "If we consider a small element of the rod with length  and mass  then the difference  between the tensions acting to the right and to the left on that element  must be sufficient to accelerate it with an acceleration of  which is the acceleration of the whole rod"

Is it because the difference is very small in comparison to F and 2F so we neglected it at the two ends while taking the limits?

Comment: @PinkAura No, you can still apply this argument to the ends of the rod. The leftmost element at end A of the rod experience a force $F$ to the left and a force $F+\delta T$ to the right, and the difference between these forces, $\delta T$, must be sufficient to accelerate the element with an acceleration of $\frac F m$.

Comment: @gandalf61 "tension will vary along the rod from  at end A to 2 at end B."
then shouldn't it(tension) be F + adm, at the end A ? and not F...

What im trying to ask is , if we consider the leftmost element at end A, force F is acting on it from left, it has acceleration, so some tension more than F must act to accelerate it right?

Comment: @PinkAura Yes, you are right if the element size greater than zero. But in the limit, as $\delta x \rightarrow 0$ then $\delta T \rightarrow 0$ as well and the tensions at the very ends of the rod are $F$ and $2F$.

Answer (score -1):

[image: image1]

Let's consider end A and end B are two objects with **same mass**.

1. **2F-F=2ma** (both end A and end B have the same mass and system moving to the right)
2. **T-F=ma** (force act on end A when the system moving to the right)

then we can obtain
F=2(T-F)

F=2T-2F

3F=2T

T=3F/2

so the tension is more than F but less than 2F      F<T<2F

correct me if I am wrong, hope this help!

Comment: Your error is that the mass of the rod is distributed along its whole length, not concentrated at its two ends. You have calculated the *average* tension along the rod, but you have not considered how the tension varies along the rod. You should consider many small masses $\delta m$ which (we assume) are evenly distributed along the length of the rod.